# Logging using Log4j taking long time

Tags: java, oracle10g

I am using Log4j logging framework to insert the log into oracle database.But the insert query in the log4j properties file is taking a lot of time to execute and making the application very slow.When I removed the logging statements from the java code, the application worked fine.At first, I thought that the insertion into DataBase is taking time , but writing the log on an external file also takes a lot of time.

Can anyone please suggest a solution?

Thank You,
Dhaval Maheshwari.

Answer (score 2):

If you application is under development then log level should be `debug` and before logging you should check for isDebugEnabled() and then log your string.

but If your application is in production then log level should be `info` and you must log minimal information in log file.

> Always use atleast two log level in your application one for debuggnig
>   mode(for development environment) and another for production mode and
>   production log should be minimal.

This is the way you can speed up you applicaiton.

> and second thing if you want to persist your logs into database then
>   create a `scheduler task` whose responsibility would be reading logs
>   from flat file and persisting them into database and schedule this to
>   run only once in a day.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest not to follow the technique u r following now.

First of all I am not sure why u r trying to log the output of log4j in DB.
Anyways if it is that necessary try something like this. Let the logfile write into a file as it is and later run a thread to dump this file from the disk when file is closed to the database as a batch process.

In this case your application will be separated from the latency of DB.

There are other solutions also using a JMS.
Where you can write it to a JMS queue and the consumer on the other hand can read the queue and write it a DB.

It depends on the kind of problem you are trying to solve though.

See of it helps

Answer (score 0):

In Logging there are levels included in. For example in production only log application level exceptions and errors[[ERROR](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/Logger.html) level].

If it's tracking logs(Such as user actions) don't write them to files, directly add them to database. Hope this helps.